# Dynamic template handing with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a table component in Knockout that can render arbitrary columns in a way that still uses Knockout for cell contents.  I'm passing an array of column definition objects into the component and an array of arbitrary row objects.  Then, I have a nested foreach structure that looks a bit like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data:rows, as:'row'}">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
    <td data-bind="html:renderCell(row)"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

With this, I can allow the 'renderCell' function for each column to return some html to go in the cell, given the context of the row viewModel.

However, what I *really* want is to be able to return a Knockout template for the cell.  I don't want to use `<script type="text/html" id="xyz">` style templates because it doesn't suit this particular application, but I can't figure out how to get Knockout to treat the output from renderCell() as a template string.

How can I do something like the following and make it work?

```
<td data-bind="template:{fn: renderCell(row)}"></td>
```

I'd like to use other components like  and other bindings in the output of the renderCell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand it, you want a custom template for each cell. This template is to be based on the information coming into the binding. The closet thing I can think of to let you do this is a custom binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

So that's the basic one from the knockout documentation. I'm guessing in the init function you can then select some html you wish to display:

```
function customTemplateOne(dataToBind) {
    var spanEl = document.createElement('span');
    spanEl.innerHTML = dataToBind;
    return spanEl;
}
```

You can have a whole bunch of different functions to define different templates.

In your init you can do this:

```
var template = "";
switch (valueToDetermineTemplateChange)
{
    case "useThis":
        template = customTemplateOne(dataToBind);
}
```

Or you can take advantage of JavaScripts key value stuff.

```
var templates = {
    useThis: function () {}
}

var template = templates[valueToDetermineTemplateChange]();
```

In order to do custom options you can do this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here

        var options = {};

        ko.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName); // get the global options
        ko.extend(options, ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())); // merge with the local options

        // so if you have a data property on the options which holds the ko binding you can do this:
        var data = ko.unwrap(options.data);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    },
    options: {
        customOption: "Some Option"
    }
};

<div data-bind="yourBindingName: { data: someValue }"></div>
```

Instead of the `applyBindingsToDescendants` function, you make your init a wrap of other bindings:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { html: valueAccessor() }, context); // the html is a binding handler, you can specify with, text, foreach....
```

Comment: But that will only work with templates in the form <script type="text/html" id="name-of-template"></script>.  I'm trying to use a function to return the template text instead of a script tag.

Comment: Thanks, but again, that just returns the 'name' of the script tag that has the template html in it, not the template text itself

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you are saying, I don't think you can have a string based template. I think what you are needing is a custom binding.

Comment: I've updated the answer, its probably not the closest thing, but hopefully should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd come across custom bindings but thought that I could use this to determine the template in that way.  I'll give it a go.  Voted up for now and will accept if I can get it to work.  Thanks for the leg-up anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult to give a complete solution here, but, you should be able to do these custom templates via the bindings, it will easily give you modularity and reuse. You can easily put all the different templates into different files, and load them up when you need them. Obviously you can create your own options as well, I can put that in the answer to.

Comment: I'm actually very close now.  I have something that basically does this: var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(row);
        $(element).html(column.renderCell(row));
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);.  This works for one row, but I think KO might be caching something because it complains about only being able to apply bindings once after the first row, using your suggestion to use a custom binding.

Comment: yeah, remove the `applyBindingsToDescendants`... that is what is messing it up. Just wrap the HTML binding

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to make the `init` into a wrap of current binding handlers

Comment: You da man.  This works: ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { html: column.renderCell(row) }, bindingContext.$parent);

Comment: Yeah, I very rarely write a purely custom binding handler, I usually just wrap the built in ones cos they cover most bases pretty well!